# Retrofit did not work only when build to apk

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, androidx

My application worked well when I am debugging by android studio.
But it did not work when I build to apk then install on device.

As I am debugging, server api is working good, but error happened when converting from json to java object (I used gson).
The problem is code is working perfectly in debugging mode (build & run from android studio) but failed when install by apk.
Anyone here get same error before?

// API call

```
getUserPrivateInfo().map(res -> {
            MZDebug.d("UserPrivateInfo", res.toString());
            CommonCheck.checkResponse(res);
            return res.getData();
});
```

// Then error: only app installed by apk

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: throw with null exception
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems to me this is related to **Proguard** configuration

to avoid this problem add a new rule into the Proguard file

```
-keep class path of your data class.** { *; }
```